UIbutton - title label not align centre. iOS 17 Swift
I have a UIButton created in XIB and linked to my uiViewController.
Its title label not align to centre. It's always align to left.
When app running from Xcode , its correctly align centre. When App quit and re-open (not with Xcode ) its left aligned always.
Tried
self.btnContinueSignIn.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
but not working. All EdgeInsects are 0,0,0,0 in xib
Setting title like this
let title = NSAttributedString(string: "Continue", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: .red])
btnContinueSignIn.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)

We need more details. What is your button Style? How are you setting the title? Are you explicitly setting the button width, or allowing it to auto-size? Screen-caps would be helpful...

autoresize is enabled. and I tried using disabled too. The tile label automatically come to left when opening app not via xib. When it run from Xcode it align center correctly

Again... we need more details. Show us your xib layout; show us how it looks when it's "correct" and how it looks when not.
